# qnorm(0.05) in R

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I read a paper, and they chose standard deviation (SD) of log(Relative Risk) as follows: 
For example, we have a normal distribution with mean of log(0.66). Then we chose the SD as

```
SD = log(0.66)/qnorm(0.05) = -0.4155154 / -1.644854 = 0.2526155
```

What I know is

```
qnorm(0.05) = P(X < -1.644854) = 0.05
```

Ultimately, they obtained samples from

```
Normal distribution with mean = log(0.66) and SD = 0.2526155.
```

My question is: I don't have any clue about what this means. What will be the purpose/meaning of dividing a value by qnorm(0.05)?

Can anyone explain what it means? Thank you!!

Comment: It gives you the quantile of distribution in this case -1.64

Comment: Are you using Markov's inequality to get the upper bound of `Pr(X > -1.644854)`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality

Comment: What is the assumed distribution of `log(RelativeRisk)`? It can't possibly be normal. Is `RelativeRisk` assumed to be normal? In any event -- this seems to be more a question for [statistics.se] than for Stack Overflow

Comment: Hi @Duck ; Yes, I acknowledge that the function gives us a quantile of distribution. However, I don't know what it means by dividing a value by this qnorm(0.05)...

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman ; There is no assumed distribution of relative risk, as it can be directly calculated by the given data. I will try to post this question in Cross Validated. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @ThomasIsCoding ; I don't think that the authors used Markov's inequality, because it only deals with nonnegative random variables (as far as I know). Thanks for the comment, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably to do with the fact that by using a standard deviation which is the mean divided by `qnorm(0.05)` the random variable then has a 95% chance of being below 0.

```
mean(rnorm(1e6, log(0.66), log(0.66)/qnorm(0.05)) < 0)
#> [1] 0.950121
```

Comment: OMG! I think this is it! It totally makes sense. Thank you, @pseudospin, so much for sharing this idea.

Comment: @rudgus51998 That might explain where it comes from, but it seems somewhat arbitrary so I wouldn't say that it totally makes sense. I agree that this is a good answer to your question but there is still some murkiness in the justification for the move.

Comment: @JohnColeman Agree. Thank you for sharing this great insight!